# How to convert List<dynamic> to List<Object> in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have made two Lists  List <Animal>  _animals and List <Animal>  _selectedanimals

```
static List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal( name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(name: "Lion"),
    Animal( name: "Panda"),
    Animal( name: "Anaconda"),];

  List<Animal> _selectedAnimals2 = [];
```

Then I made a multiselect sheet where the user can select his favorite animals
and on confirm/or selected by the user the selected values  are stored in a dynamic List named as values and from List<dynamic> values it is stored into another list List<Animal> _selectedAnimals2 but i m getting an error which is mentioned below :

**type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Animal>'**

```
MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                         initialChildSize: 0.4,
                         listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                         searchable: true,
                         buttonText: Text("Favorite Animals",style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.white),),
                         title: Text("Animals"),
                         items: _items,
                         onConfirm: (values) {
                            _selectedAnimals2=values;
                            final List<String> choose=_selectedAnimals2.map((Animal animal) => animal.name).toList();
                           saveUserInfoToFireStore(choose);
                         },
```

Answer (score 23):

if we want to convert list dynamic to its type, we can use the method `cast()`

```
List sample = ["test1", "test2"]; /// dynamic list

List<String> stringList = []; /// string list

/// for casting
stringList = sample.cast<String>();
```

Similarly, we can convert our lists

```
List<CustomModel> list = dynamicList.cast<CustomModel>();
```

Comment: This worked <3, tks bro, you just saved my out of deadline & task :D

Answer (score 1):

```
List<CustomModel> toResponseList(List<dynamic> data) {
    List<CustomModel> value = <CustomModel>[];
    data.forEach((element) {
      value.add(NasaResponseModel.fromJson(element));
    });
    return value ?? List<CustomModel>.empty();
  }
```

works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

if your _items is List of Strings you can try this

```
_selectedAnimals2 = values.map((val) => Animal( name: val)).toList()
```